# Server Response conflicts

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

i have an issue regarding deployment of my project on 1 and 1 server using plesk.

The Issue is :

on my previous hosting JSON response of server was in string although they were stored as integer in database but as i deployed the code on the 1 and 1 , it is returning int as int and Varchar as string ,
the confusion isat this time i cant change datatypes of system to Varchar, i need a solution to convert whole response in string using any extension or something you suggest.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: If its same code you need to look for other differences in environment, PHP version, DB version (the most likely). If you *remigrated* your database and you use migration `->json()` it may behave differently than you think.

Comment: you can use casting like this if it is integer then 
int ($variable);